# Ploting a numpy array as an image

Tags: python, arrays, image

I have temperature vales as function of time at 34 different points forming an array of (200,34) shape. How can I represent the data in the array as an image. I search online but I did not find any useful solutions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you envisage the image might look?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably interested in matplotlib's [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function:

```py
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from numpy.random import uniform
image = uniform(size = (200, 32))
imshow(image, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have plotted the data and showed an  image. However, it has a white line appears, and I do not know why. I doubled checked the values in the array and all of the are finite. Also, the grid lines are off. Any suggested reason why the white line appear in the image?.

Comment: This would be easier if you could provide the data. Maybe the contrast limit is off, you can adapt it by using attributes vmin and vmax : imshow( image , vmax=100 , vmin=0 )